# Why the set of pure state ‎is ‎weak* ‎compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let ‎$‎‎A$ ‎be a‎ ‎C*-algebra‎.

‎
‎$‎S(A)‎$ ‎is ‎the ‎set ‎of ‎state ‎on ‎‎$‎‎A$ and $‎‎PS(A)$ ‎is ‎the ‎set ‎of ‎pure ‎state ‎on ‎‎$‎‎A$.

‎
‎
I ‎know ‎that ‎if ‎‎$‎‎A$ ‎is ‎unital ‎then ‎‎$‎‎S(A)$ ‎is ‎weak* ‎compat.‎

‎I know that  extreme points of $S(A)$ is $PS(A)$

I ‎want ‎to ‎prove ‎‎$‎‎PS(A)$ ‎is ‎weak* ‎compact.so I‎ ‎should ‎show ‎that ‎‎$‎‎PS(A)$ ‎is ‎weak* ‎closed.(when $A$ is unital)

‎
Q: ‎‎My question is:"  Why $‎PS(A)‎$ ‎is ‎weak* ‎compact?‎" 
" Is the extreme point of compact set compact?
"

Answer (score 2):

The set of pure states of a unital C$^*$-algebra is weak$^*$-compact when $A$ is abelian, but not in general.

This has been known since at least [Glimm's thesis](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-095-02/S0002-9947-1960-0112057-5/), where he proved that the set of pure states of a UHF algebra is not closed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{\phi\}$ be a net of pure states on $A$ and assume that it is $w^*$-convergent to $\phi$. Clearly $\phi$ is a positive linear functional on $A$.

To prove $\phi$ is a pure state, it is enough to show that support of $\phi$ is a minimal projection in $A^{**}$. Assume $q$ is  a non-trivial projection majorized by the support of $\phi$. We have that $q\phi_i q$ is  $w^*$-convergent to $q\phi q$ then there is a subnet $\{\phi_j\}$ such that $q\phi_jq=\phi_j$. It implies that $\phi=q\phi q$ which means that $q\geq$supp($\phi$). Hence support of $\phi$ is minimal.

Comment: It's a bit late. But can you please explain why "there is a subnet $\{\phi_j\}$ such that $1\phi_j1=\phi_j$? Also, how to conclude from $q\geq \text{supp}(\phi)$ that $\phi$ is pure? I'm new to C*-algebra, sorry.

Comment: Also, isn't $\text{supp}(\phi)$ a subset of $A$? So what does $q\geq \text{supp}(\phi)$ even mean? Does it mean $q\geq a_\phi$, for every $a_\phi\in \text{supp}(\phi)$?

Comment: I mean, isn't $q$ an element of $A$? So what does $q\phi_i q$ mean, since $\phi_i$ is a functional on $A$?

Comment: @user760: the support of $\phi$ in this context means (as said in the answer) the *support projection* of $\phi$. The notation $q\phi q$ is standard for $\phi(q\cdot q)$; it reflects a common perspective in algebra where you can consider $A^*$ as a module over $A$. And $q$ is not in $A$, which for all we know could be projectionless; it is in $A^{**}$, the double dual/enveloping von Neumann algebra of $A$. In any case the answer is wrong, as there are well known counterexamples.