# Cyclic vectors in irreducible GNS representation of pure states

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I have a confusion regarding the unit cyclic vectors in the GNS construction of pure states. It seems every corresponding GNS representation $(\mathcal{H}_f, \varphi_f)$ of a pure state $f$ of a unital C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, should have its unique unit cyclic vector $x_f \in \mathcal{H}_f$. However, I also see a claim (forgot where) that for every non-zero unit vector $x\in \mathcal{H}_f\setminus \{0\}$, such that $\|x\|=1$, we always have, for $a\in\mathcal{A}$,
$$f(a)=\left\langle \varphi_f(a)x,x\right\rangle.$$
So for example, if $f(a)>0$ for every pure state $f$, we can conclude that $\varphi_f(a)$ is always a self-adjoint positive definite operator. Then, deduce that $a$ is positive in $\mathcal{A}$.

But is this correct? Shouldn't this equality only hold for the unique $x_f$ obtained from the GNS construction? Am I missing something? Is this a special property for pure states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also see a claim

You don't say where, so I cannot comment on that.

For any $b\in A$ such that $f(b^*b)=1$ you have that $\hat b=\phi_f(b)x_f$ is a unit vector, and
$$
\langle \phi_f(a)\hat b,\hat b\rangle=\langle\phi_f(a)\phi_f(b)x_f,\phi_f(b)x_f\rangle=\langle\phi_f(b^*ab)x_f,x_f\rangle=f(b^*ab).
$$
So the assertion is not true as stated.

Now, if $f(a)≥0$ for all pure states then $a$ is positive. This follows from the fact that the state space is the weak$^*$ closure of the convex hull of the pure states. Then $f(a)≥0$ for all states and so $a≥0$.

Comment: I guess I should ask it this way: if $(H, \varphi)$ is the direct sum of irreducible GNS representations $(H_f, \varphi_f)$, where $f$ runs through pure states, then how to conclude that the linear functional $\tau_h: a \mapsto \langle \varphi(a) h, h \rangle$ is a positive operator? I know each $\tau_{h_f}$ is positive for $h_f$ the corresponding unit cyclic vector.

Comment: Or if we are talking about the universal representation. The cofusion is this: for each corresponding GNS representation, I can see why the functional is positive. But for the direct sum, we can't use the GNS construction and directly concluse it is. Maybe I misunderstood something in the GNS construction?

Comment: But that has nothing to do with GNS. If  $a$ is positive, then $a=b^*b$. For any representation $\phi$ and any $h$, $$\langle\phi(a)h,h\rangle=\langle\phi(b)^*\phi(b)h,h \rangle=\|\phi(b)h \|^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Thank you. So this is true for all $*$-homomorphisms

Comment: Indeed. $ \ \ $

Comment: Can you please elaborate the last paragraph in your answer? Specifically, the part where you claim "if there is a state $\tilde{g}(a)=0$, then there exists a pure state $f(a)=0$? I don't get why the canonical evaluation map being weak*-continuous guarantees that.

Comment: Also, for a faithful representation $\pi: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, if $\pi(a)$ is positive definite in $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, why can we directly conclude $a$ is positive in $\mathcal{A}$? What if $\pi$ can also map some non-positive elements to positive definite operators?

Comment: If $f(a)>0$ for all pure states, the set of pure states (compact when $\mathcal A$ is unital) is mapped to a compact subset $C$ of $(0, \|a\|]$. Take $c=\min C$. As for the representation, a faithful representation is injective, and $\mathcal A\simeq\pi(\mathcal A)$.

Comment: May I ask why the set of all pure states is weak-* compact? Is it mentioned in Murphy (1990)? 

For the faithful representation, my confusion is, just because it's injective, doesn't mean other elements can't be mapped to positive operators, right? Sorry if the question is silly...

Comment: I'm thinking I was wrong, and that it isn't necessarily closed; I'll check. As for the representation, an isomorphism of C$^*$-algebras preserves positivity.

Comment: Can you understand this answer?? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1635924/416552

Comment: No. In any case, it's wrong, as the set of pure states is known to be non-closed is some (most?) cases. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/102310/3698). I'm deleting that part of my answer, if I come up with something I'll answer your other question.